# Why make private static final Lists/Sets/Maps unmodifiable?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, constants, immutability

I just read some code written by a more experienced programmer, and I came across the following:

```
public class ConsoleFormatter extends Formatter {
    private static final Map<Level, String> PREFIXES;

    static {
        Map<Level, String> prefixes = new HashMap<Level, String>();
        prefixes.put(Level.CONFIG,  "[config]");
        prefixes.put(Level.FINE,    "[debug]");
        prefixes.put(Level.FINER,   "[debug]");
        prefixes.put(Level.FINEST,  "[trace]");
        prefixes.put(Level.INFO,    "[info]");
        prefixes.put(Level.SEVERE,  "[error]");
        prefixes.put(Level.WARNING, "[warning]");

        PREFIXES = Collections.unmodifiableMap(prefixes);
    }

    // ...

}
```

As you can see, this is a class used for formatting log output. What caught my eye, however, was the code in the static initializer block: `PREFIXES = Collections.unmodifiableMap(prefixes);`.

Why was `PREFIXES` made an unmodifiable map? **It's a private constant, so there's no risk of modifying the data outside of that class.** Was it done to give the constant's immutability a sense of completeness?

Personally, I would've directly initialized `PREFIXES` as a `HashMap` and then `put` the key–value pairs in directly, without creating a dummy, placeholder map or making the field an immutable map. Am I missing something here?

Comment: It might also be _thought_ to prevent concurrent initialisation problems when instantiating the class, because of the single step assignment to PREFIXES of the entire data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By making the list unmodifiable the author documented his assumption that the values will never change. Whoever might edit that class later on can not only see that assumption, but will also be reminded in case it is ever broken.

This makes sense only when taking the longer-term view. It reduces the risk of new problems arising through maintenance. I like to do this style of programming, because I tend to break stuff even in my own classes. One day you might go in for a quick fix and you forget about an assumption that was made originally and is relevant for correctness. The more you can lock the code down, the better.

Comment: _"One day you might go in for a quick fix and you forget about an assumption that was made originally and is relevant for correctness."_

Oh boy, I know exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 9):

If you accidentally `return PREFIXES` from a method, suddenly any other code out there can modify it.  Making constants truly immutable defends against your own stupidity when you modify that code in the future at 3AM.

Comment: exactly... Otherwise `final` would be incomplete for the `Map<Level, String> PREFIXES` map.

Answer (score 3):

It's surprisingly easy to have a `private` map, collection or array which is modifiable from outside the class. You'd mark it `final`, why wouldn't also spell out that it is supposed to be immutable as well?

Comment: I see your point, but there are no getters for the mentioned field. Are you saying that it's good practice to make them immutable anyway, just in case?

Comment: @KonstantinĐ. Doesn't need to be a getter. My favourite example is in Michael Feather's Working With Legacy Code. In chapter 13 he goes into the most incredible tedious detail about how objects can leak. And the in chapter 14, he exposes a `private static` array. If he does that, then I'm not expecting a normal programmer to get it right - unless they very explicitly hide the mutable object behind an unmodifiable wrapper.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose your friend leaves his job and a less experienced programmer takes over. The less experienced programmer attempts to modify the contents of PREFIXES somewhere in a different method within the same class. It it's unmodifiable, it won't work. It's the proper way to say "this is a constant, don't ever change it."

Answer (score 1):

The Map interface does not communicate that you want something to be immutable or unmodifiable.

The following approaches will work in [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/).

```
private static final ImmutableMap<Level, String> PREFIXES = UnifiedMap.<Level, String>newMap()
    .withKeyValue(Level.CONFIG, "[config]")
    .withKeyValue(Level.FINE, "[debug]")
    .withKeyValue(Level.FINER, "[debug]")
    .withKeyValue(Level.FINEST, "[trace]")
    .withKeyValue(Level.INFO, "[info]")
    .withKeyValue(Level.SEVERE, "[error]")
    .withKeyValue(Level.WARNING, "[warning]")
    .toImmutable();
```

This will create a Map that is contractually immutable, because ImmutableMap has no mutating methods in its API.

If you prefer to to keep the Map interface, this approach will work as well.

```
private static final Map<Level, String> PREFIXES = UnifiedMap.<Level, String>newMap()
    .withKeyValue(Level.CONFIG, "[config]")
    .withKeyValue(Level.FINE, "[debug]")
    .withKeyValue(Level.FINER, "[debug]")
    .withKeyValue(Level.FINEST, "[trace]")
    .withKeyValue(Level.INFO, "[info]")
    .withKeyValue(Level.SEVERE, "[error]")
    .withKeyValue(Level.WARNING, "[warning]")
    .asUnmodifiable();
```

You should notice there is no need for the static block in either of the cases.

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 0):

If a collection is made final, you cannot set a new object into it.
However, it is still possible to add or remove items to the same object.

When you make it unmodifiable, you cannot even add or remove items to the collection.
Hence, it is always advised to make the collection Unmodifiable instead of just keeping it as final.